# Looking for clarification regarding array references in function definitions and prototypes

Tags: c++, arrays

I get the idea that to MODIFY an array in another function I need to declare the parameter as a reference in the function definition:

```
bool sortInput(ifstream &infile, StudentType (&students)[MAXSIZE], int size)
```

And I declared the prototype similarly since it wouldn't compile properly otherwise:

```
bool sortInput(ifstream &, StudentType (&students)[MAXSIZE], int);
```

However this doesn't seem to actually pass the array as a reference. I make a call to a different function and it doesn't see any of the changes (all it does is print the array but it prints nothing). I know for a fact that the array has been modified because printing it WITHIN the original function shows all the changes, they simply don't seem to carry over to the global array variable and stay within the scope of the function that modifies it despite being passed as a reference.

I've read countless other threads and Google searches so I'm fairly sure the function definition is proper however nowhere does it state the proper form for the prototype.

Comment: Any reason why this isn't a `vector` instead of an array?

Comment: ... or an `std::array` for that matter.

Comment: @Jefffrey It shouldn't be an `std::array` because the size is very clearly not known at compile  time, as you can see because the function has a `size` parameter.

Comment: It's an assignment in which we're required to use array and an insertion sort to alphabetize. Guess for learning purposes. The code does have "using namespace std" so wouldnt that make it an std::array?

Comment: No, `std::array` is templated container that provides additional features over the C/C++ language construct known as an array. All `using namespace std` does it makes it so that the qualification: `std::` before `array` is unnecessary.

Comment: @WhozCraig: That was in response to the OP, so it is addressing a problem he is having, whether the prior comments unnecessarily introduced it or not.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Ah.. look at that. for sure. +1 on your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to pass array by reference because it passed as pointer. Pass size. In your sort function copy of variable size is modified but in your main function it always zero.

Comment: So changed it to "&size" and removed all the array reference crud I was trying to do and everything works properly now. Thank you! Though this confuses me even more now... so does everything you wish to modify (with the exception of arrays) need to be passed as a reference?

Comment: yes or by pointer. Array passed by pointer already so you can modify its content. To pass by pointer some variable use `int var; foo(&var);` and function will be `void foo(int *var) { int another_var = *var; }`. Try to fing some articles about poiters and references in c++. It makes things clear.

Answer (score 1):

An array is already passed as a pointer, so you can already modify its contents. Adding `&` isn't required.

Comment: Not to this OP, but it is, however, important if you want to require a *specific* declared array size. `func(int ar[]`) will take anything, including a dynamic pointer, etc. But `func(int (&ar)[SIZE])` *requires* the caller only invoke with an actual `int[SIZE]` array. Passing an `int ar[5]` will result in a compile-time-error, for example.